# Why is the OSX system Ruby being used instead of RVM default (SilverStripe-Compass module)

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, silverstripe, compass-geolocation

I recently updated SilverStripe on my dev server to v3.0.5 using Composer which happened to pull in the silverstripe-compass module.  I happen to use compass externally (not the SilverStripe module).

On trying to rebuild the site `/dev/build?flush=all` I get the following error:

```
[User Error] Compass Error:LoadError on line 36 of /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb: no such file to load -- bundler/setupRun with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

It appears that the old OSX Ruby is being used and the RVM managed default Ruby is being ignored, when SilverStripe tries to execute a compass build.

The default RVM ruby (from bash):

```
$ which ruby
  /Users/myosx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
```

Any ideas how I can prevent this from happening?  How can I prevent the OSX Ruby from being used?

Comment: did you try executing this command with `bundle exec` ? from time to time there are some old remains in the path...

Comment: Thanks for your response @phoet. Which command do you mean to run `bundle exec` with?

Comment: well, the command that fails?! or is that embedded somewhere? i have no idea what silverstripe is...

Comment: Yeah - the command is embedded (SilverStripe is a PHP Framework + CMS).  Thanks for the pointer - I'll dig into the code to have a look.

Comment: @Prembo, were you able to solve your issue for this? If so, it might be worthwhile to post an answer to your own question saying what you needed to do.